# Como Agrupar Atributo en una clase con C#

Tags: c#, linq

quisiera que me puedan ayudar tengo 3 instancia de una clase que tienen los atributos
periodo,soles_vac,dolares_vac,gastos

por la cual en cada instancia tengo en mismo periodo diferentes montos en diferentes atributos
yo quisiera que solo obtenga ahora que por periodo
ya obtenga los atributos asi como la imagen

lo realize con linq mediante un groupby pero no obtuve lo que requeria.

```
public static list<Flujo>Crear(List<Flujo> ListaFlujo)
{
return ListaFlujo.GroupBy(f =>f.periodo).Select(f =>new FlujoSP
{
periodo = f.FirstOrDefault().Periodo,
Soles_vac =f.FirstOrDefault().Soles_vac ,
Dolares_vac  =f.FirstOrDefault().Dolares_vac   ,
gastos = f.FirstOrDefault().gastos
}).ToList();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y si agregas el comportamiento esperado, dando un ejemplo donde se pueda percibir lo que intentaste, además de "todo lo que has intentado" (esto lo dijiste por chat privado)?

Comment: @fredyfx edite la imagen tengo una clase que tiene los periodo y quisiea que una clase diferente quede como la clase final

Comment: Y cuales son las reglas del merge, ya que por cada agrupacion de periodo tendras entre uno o mas subitem. Siempre tendras dos item por cada periodo o podrian ser mas o uno.

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo que despues de la agrupacion valides item por item los valores que quieras obtener.

```
public static List<Flujo> Crear(List<Flujo> ListaFlujo)
{
    List<Flujo> listaFlujoFinal = new List<Flujo>();

    Flujo flujoNuevo;
    Flujo flujoTemp;

    List<IGrouping<int, Flujo>> listaFlujoAgrupado = ListaFlujo.GroupBy(f => f.Periodo).ToList();

    foreach (IGrouping<int, Flujo> periodoAgrupado in listaFlujoAgrupado)
    {
        flujoNuevo = new Flujo();

        flujoNuevo.Periodo = periodoAgrupado.Key;

        // buscando la primera coincidencia donde Soles_vac contenga valor.
        flujoTemp = periodoAgrupado.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Soles_vac != 0);

        if (flujoTemp != null) flujoNuevo.Soles_vac = flujoTemp.Soles_vac;

        // buscando la primera coincidencia donde Dolares_vac contenga valor.
        flujoTemp = periodoAgrupado.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Dolares_vac != 0);

        if (flujoTemp != null) flujoNuevo.Dolares_vac = flujoTemp.Dolares_vac;

        listaFlujoFinal.Add(flujoNuevo);
    }

    return listaFlujoFinal;
}
```

Dentro del foreach puede agregar mas reglas de validaciones, por ejemplo si solo encuentras un periodo o si hay mas periodos.

En el fragmento de codigo que dejo me estoy suponiendo que `Periodo` es un entero y que `Soles_vac` y `Dolares_vac` son decimales.

Comment: una consulta ahi solo buscamos la primera que esta al comienzo y que pasaria si hay valores abajo con el mismo periodo ?

Comment: Para eso debes de definir una seria de reglas, las cuales no has proporcionado, por eso cualquier otra regla o validacion la puedes agregar en el foreach

Comment: Por ejemplo: que pasa si al agrupar periodo `1` contiene 5 subitem, cuales de los 5 valores se debe de elejir?.

Comment: Si periodo `1` contiene dos subitem, pero tanto dolares_vac y soles_vac contienen informacion, Cual seleciono?

Comment: edite mi pregunta con la imagen solo del periodo 0 para tener un ejemplo

Comment: Segun tu actualizacion solo se seleciono el primer valor encontrado? Si es asi entonces el ejemplo que das en tu respuesta es el correcto, quizas lo que te falta definir es algun tipo de ordenamiento.